# Binding mouse buttons with Razer DeathAdder not working

Tags: diablo-iii

I am playing Diablo 3 and it appears that binding actions to left and right click on the Razer DeathAdder work just great. However, as soon as I want to bind keys to the buttons on the side of the mouse, it will not take hold. Is there a way to enable those additional buttons on Razer mice so we can bind them and use them in D3? I use this mouse extensively in world of warcraft and it works just great otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your death-adder needs to be configured so that the buttons that aren't binding are set to something that D3 recognizes. General buttons aren't always detected.

One option would be to map the mouse buttons to a keyboard key that isn't used in game, and won't trigger anything in your operating system (usually | or ~ are good options). Then Diablo will see that mouse click as | or ~ instead. I had to do something like this with my Logitech g700 and WoW. It worked fine after.